# rails 2.3 creating without saving the name but saving the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format, save

I am able to create a new clipList but the name(john) is not saved it saves the path(`/asset/clip_list/56`) instead! and I get this in the address bar after clicking on create
`localhost:3000/asset/clip_lists.%23 asset::cliplist:0x7fb4f09751b0\>` and a blank page instead of reloading the page with the newly created clip(localhost:3000/asset/clip_list/56).

Here my function

```
def create
    @clip_list = Asset::ClipList.new(params[:clip_list])
    @clip_list.owner = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @clip_list.save
        flash[:notice] = 'ClipList was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to(asset_clip_lists_path(@clip_list)) }# asset_clip_lists_path =  /asset/clip_lists
       format.xml  { render :xml => @clip_list, :status => :created, :location => @clip_list }
     else
       format.html { render :action => "new" }
       format.xml  { render :xml => @clip_list.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
   end
end
```

What is wrong? Here is my model **clip_list.rb**

```
class Asset::ClipList < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :assets_development
  set_table_name "clip_lists"
  has_many :asset_clips
  has_many :clip_lists_users
  has_many :users, :through  => :clip_lists_users
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner"
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

here is my **_form.haml**

```
form_for(@clip_list, :url => asset_clip_lists_path(@clip_list), :html => {:class => 'form'}) do |f|   
.group  
    = f.label 'Name', 'Name', :class => 'label'  
    = f.text_field :name, :class => "text"  
    %span.description A short name for your clip list  
  .group  
    = f.label 'Description', 'Description', :class => 'label'  
    = f.text_field :description, :class => 'text'  
  .group  
    = f.submit create_or_update(@clip_list).humanize
```

Here are the **rake routes**

```
asset_clip_lists     GET      /asset/clip_lists(.:format)                               {:controller=>"asset/asset/clip_lists", :action=>"index"}  
                     POST     /asset/clip_lists(.:format)                               {:controller=>"asset/clip_lists", :action=>"create"}  
new_asset_clip_list  GET      /asset/clip_lists/new(.:format)                           {:controller=>"asset/clip_lists", :action=>"new"}    
edit_asset_clip_list GET    /asset/clip_lists/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:controller=>"asset/asset/clip_lists", :action=>"edit"}  
                     GET      /asset/clip_lists/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"asset/clip_lists", :action=>"show"}  
                     PUT      /asset/clip_lists/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"asset/clip_lists", :action=>"update"}  
                     DELETE   /asset/clip_lists/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"asset/clip_lists", :action=>"destroy"}  
delete_asset_clip_list        /asset/clip_list/:id/destroy                              {:controller=>"asset/clip_lists", :action=>"destroy"}  
asset_clip_list              /asset/clip_list/:id                                      {:controller=>"asset/clip_lists", :action=>"show"}
```

Here is **route.rb**

```
map.namespace :asset do |asset|  
asset.resources :clip_lists, :controller => 'asset/clip_lists'  
map.delete_asset_clip_list 'asset/clip_list/:id/destroy', :controller => 'asset/clip_lists', :action => 'destroy'  
map.asset_clip_list 'asset/clip_list/:id', :controller => 'asset/clip_lists', :action => 'show'
```

Asset is just another app nested in my app folder so you have

```
app/controllers/asset/all asset controllers  
app/models/asset/all asset model  
...
```

I don't have a table asset in my DB its just the namespace I used for the nested app
here is the **new**

```
def new  
    @clip_list = Asset::ClipList.new  
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.html # new.haml  
      format.xml  { render :xml => @clip_list }  
    end  
  end
```

Actually a new cliplist is creating but doesn't save the attributes and give the path (localhost:3000/asset/clip_list/56) as name

Comment: please reformat your code. It's hard to read for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks,hope the reformat help

Comment: Great. I could see that some things might go wrong in your ClipList model. Could you please show what's inside ClipList model?

Comment: my problem is with form_for...

Comment: the @clip_list in the controller create function was the problem!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't got the routes right. In terminal, I would type "`rake routes`" to check what the route for `asset_clip_lists_path` is. If you don't have it right, when you submit the form it won't go to the right place.

I would also check the class of `@clip_list` in the view with `@clip_list.class` to see if it's the correct class "Asset::ClipList".

Also, I don't get the idea of you having the class name as "Asset::ClipList". If you are trying to achieve Single Table Inheritance, you should try this.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...

end

class ClipList < Asset
   ...
end
```

You can read more about STI [here](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/).

Comment: thanks Phyo Wai Win **@clip_list.class** is giving **NilClass** in the view

Comment: i fixed the route issue by removing asset/ in routes.rb. how to fix the NilClass issue? asset_clip_lists_path is pointing to the right page(the index). sorry i have pb with formatting!

Comment: If you have Nil object for "@clip_list" at New view, you have a problem setting it up in your Controller's "new" action. Check in there how you are setting the "@clip_list". Could you show your "new" action method from your controller?

Comment: Phyo Wai Win i am able to create now by changing: **@clip_list = Asset::ClipList.new(params[:clip_list])** with **@clip_list = Asset::ClipList.new(params[:asset_clip_list])**   but it's still not rendering the page....i still have **localhost:3000/asset/clip_lists.%23 asset::cliplist:0x7fb4f09751b0\>** in the address bar.

Comment: if i do **form_for(@clip_list, :html => {:class => 'form'}) do |f|** it render correctly but doesn't create nor update.